# Is "farther of which the ball has fallen" correct?

Tags: phrase-usage

Here is the situation:

A boy is throwing a ball onto a field that is divided into several lines. Each line is 10 meters wide and has its own color. The boy is throwing his basketball across those lines. Since the ball is rather heavy, it will not fly far and will land on one of those lines. When the ball has finally landed and come to a rest, there will be quite a few lines between the boy and the line with the ball, as well as between the line with the ball and the end of the field.

Now imagine that every third line has a red dot on it. The ball, therefore, may land on a line with a dot, or it may not.

Now, I am writing an instruction for a new PE teacher in elementary school on how to play a certain ball game with students:

> 1. Ask a student to throw the ball across the field lines as far as
>    possible;
> 2. Wait till the ball lands and comes to a rest;
> 3. Come up to the farthest dotted line, on which or **farther of
>    which the ball has fallen**, and place a brick on that
>    line's dot;

I wonder if it's a correct way to say that in English (the phrase that I put in bold)?

Comment: Is this a **real** situation?

Comment: @JamesK - No. I just came up with it in order to sort of illustrate my question.

Comment: Is there a real problem to solve?

Comment: @JamesK - That IS the real problem. I run in situations like that, use that phrase, and then stop and think whether what I said was correct or not.

Comment: If you run in to situations like that, it might be better to describe an actual situation that you run into, rather than try to create an artificial one.  However I've written an answer.

Comment: _Beyond which_, and _further than which_ are both possible, and have the meaning you want. _Further from which_ is also meaningful, but has a different meaning. _Further of which_ is meaningless. Note that I have used _further_ rather than _farther_: _farther_ exists in my vocabulary, but not in everyday speech except in certain fixed phrases.

Comment: @JamesK - "it might be better to describe an actual situation that you run into, rather than try to create an artificial one" - I am afraid it won't help you much. Replace the field with a classroom table, the ball with a marble, the brick with an eraser, and the instructions for a teacher with instructions for a student, and you will get the real situation that I ran into. I was still not sure, though, if what I was saying was correct.

Comment: @ColinFine - "_Beyond which_, and _further than which_ are both possible" - Can you, please, give me an example with "_further than which_"?

Comment: Brilliant, you could substitute it in your example: _the furthest dotted line on which or further than which the ball has fallen_. It's quite stilted, but almost any use of _which_ after a preposition is stilted.

Comment: @ColinFine - I see. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are trying to say

> If the ball lands on a dotted line, place a brick on the dot; if the ball lands between two dotted lines, place a brick on the dot in the line farther from the boy.

Conciseness may be a virtue, but comprehensibility is a greater one. If you have different instructions for different circumstances, explain each circumstance and what is to be done in each. Trying to jam it all into a single phrase just results in unclear instructions.

Comment: "place a brick on the dot in the line farther from the boy" - Well, actually it should be opposite:  in the line closer to the boy, given that the boy didn't leave the place, from which he was throwing the ball.

Comment: Well then why did you say "farther" rather than "closer"?

Comment: Because if the boy is standing at the line A and the ball has landed on, say, line P, that is between two dotted lines O and R, the ball is now _farther_ than the line O; however, from among the two dotted lines O and R, between which the ball has landed, you should choose (for placing a brick) the one that is _closer_ to the boy, that is, the line O.

Comment: How do I know what you meant to convey. It is simple enough to say "farther from the bot" or "closer to the boy." You chose "farthest," which clearly is not correct.

Comment: I see. So, what would be the right way to say that?

Comment: Look at my answer. If you meant “closer to the boy” instead of “farther from the boy,” say “closer.” Trying to condense too much thought into just a few words does not work.

Comment: Got it. Thank you!